# JS Test for :target support

Tags: javascript, css

I'm writing some code that involves CSS tabs, but IE doesn't support the :target css3 attribute. I have a work around by checking the hash value in an interval (ew), but I want to only have that code run when :target is not supported. I would do the regular IE check, except early versions of Firefox do not support it, nor does early Safari or Opera. Does anyone know how to test for :target support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for CSS support by adding a rule like `#someid:target { visibility:hidden; color:#abcdef; }` and then setting the target to `#someid`, reading if the color is `#abcdef`, and then reseting the hash.

This will, however, generate entries in the browser history: 1 for when you navigate to the id, and 1 for when you reset it to whatever it was before. It may also create a flicker in your tabs, so that may not be ideal - but I don't know what you can get away with.

Ideally, tabs should ideally read and write the hash for bookmarkability. But I don't think that `:target` is the ideal solution to creating tabs. I know it looks appealing to begin with ([did to me](http://borgar.net/svn/public/trunk/javascript/jquery.minitabs/)). Given the poor support of the selector, how badly it scales with nested or multiple tabs, and how volatile it becomes with other markup (someone adds a #skip-to link on the page), it is less headache to implement with good old clicks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I think I might manipulate the hash so you can link into the tabs, but not rely on them for the display (read "css").